# html headline with logo on the right side

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am trying to display the logo on the right side, next to a centered headline

I have tried several combinations of display:inline and float but it seems like the centered attribute of the h1 headline doesnt really work in that combination.

Can you please let me know what is the correct way of doing it? For example put the logo into the css? Any hint on how to solve the issue is welcome

Comment: show up your code !

Comment: could you please share what you already tried?

Comment: i dont want to show my code as i've been fiddling with it and it doesnt work. where is the point??

I was more focussed in getting a hint on howto implement this the proper way instead of fiddling my code until it works...

https://jsfiddle.net/nfb7ns54/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to positioning as like below snippet.

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  padding:0;  
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>My Heading</h1>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="logo-img" alt="logo">
</header>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this answer. so the attribute combination: img absolute and h1 center does the trick. i still had the display: inline in the css and this destroys the result. THANK YOU